# xaml wpf надо чтобы окно растягивалось вместе с grid

Tags: wpf, xaml

Мне надо растянуть окно по ширине высоте элементов внутри, я делаю видимыми поля collapsed, но по мере того как полей становится больше окно уже не вмещает все, а использовать ползунки нельзя.

```
<window>
 <grid>
   <UniformGrid  Visibility="Collapsed" />
   <TextBlock  Visibility="Collapsed" />
 <grid>

</window>
```

и получается мне надо чтобы окно растягивалось вместе с grid

Answer (score 3):

Если в окне только `grid`, то лучше всего использовать свойство окна `SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"`

Comment: @СашаЧерных спасибо! понял свою ошибку.